# Recursive remove in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to remove the element from linked list recursively, but the remove function is not working. I need some help in solving this.

My node.h function

```cpp
#ifndef NODE_  
#define NODE_

template<class ItemType> 
class Node { 
private:
    ItemType item; // A data item    
    Node<ItemType>* next; // Pointer to next node
public:
    Node();
    Node(const ItemType& anItem);
    Node(const ItemType& anItem, Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr);

    void setItem(const ItemType& anItem);
    void setNext(Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr);
    ItemType getItem() const;
    Node<ItemType>* getNext() const;
}; // end Node

#include "Node.cpp"
#endif
```

My node.cpp file:

```cpp
#include "Node.h" 

template<class ItemType>
Node<ItemType>::Node() : next(nullptr)
{
} // end default constructor

template<class ItemType>
Node<ItemType>::Node(const ItemType& anItem) : item(anItem), next(nullptr)
{
} // end constructor

template<class ItemType>
Node<ItemType>::Node(const ItemType& anItem, Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr) :
                item(anItem), next(nextNodePtr)
{
} // end constructor

template<class ItemType>
void Node<ItemType>::setItem(const ItemType& anItem)
{
   item = anItem;
} // end setItem

template<class ItemType>
void Node<ItemType>::setNext(Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr)
{
   next = nextNodePtr;
} // end setNext

template<class ItemType>
ItemType Node<ItemType>::getItem() const
{
   return item;
} // end getItem

template<class ItemType>
Node<ItemType>* Node<ItemType>::getNext() const
{
   return next;
} // end getNext
```

My main function:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "Node.h"

using namespace std;

// Function to insert an item into the front of a linked list
template<class T>
void insert(Node<T>* &headPtr, const T& entry)
{
    // Create a new node and have the next pointer point to current front
    Node<T> *newNodePtr = new Node<T>( entry , headPtr );
    // Current front now becomes this new node
    headPtr = newNodePtr;
}

// Recursive function to remove an item from a linked list
// Returns true if the operation was done; false, otherwise
template< typename T >
bool removes(Node<T>* &nodePtr, T target)
{
    if(!nodePtr)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(nodePtr->getNext() != NULL) 
    {
        Node<T>*next = nodePtr->getNext();

        removes(next,target);

        if(nodePtr->getNext()->getItem()==target)
        {
            Node<T>*del = nodePtr;
            nodePtr->setNext(nodePtr->getNext()->getNext());
            delete del;
            return true;
        }
        //nodePtr->setNext(nodePtr->getNext());
    }
}

// Recursive function to display the contents of a linked list
// in the reverse order.
template<class T>
void display(Node<T> *currNodePtr)
{
    // YOUR CODE GOES HERE - CHECK YOUR NOTES!
    Node<T> *curr=currNodePtr;
    if(curr!=NULL)
    {   
        cout<<curr->getItem();
        display(curr->getNext());   
    }

    cout<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    // (1) Declare an empty linked list of unsigned values
    //     based on the Node class and call it myList
    Node<unsigned>*myList;

    // (2) Read in values from standard input. Non-negative
    //     values are inserted into myList and a negative
    //     value terminates input.
    int data=0;
    unsigned k;
    while(cin>>data)
    {
        if (data>=0)
        {
            k=data;
            insert(myList,k);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout<<"out of loop";
        
    // (3) Display the contents of the linked list myList
    //     in the order they were entered (hence, the display()
    //     function displays myList in reverse order!
    display(myList);

    // (4) Read in values from standard input. Non-negative
    //     values are removed from myList and a negative
    //     value terminates input.
    int data1=0;
    unsigned m;

    while(cin>>data1)
    {
        if (data1>=0)
        {
            m=data1;
            removes(myList,m);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // (5) Display the contents of the linked list myList
    //     in the order they were entered (hence, the display()
    //     function displays myList in reverse order!
    cout<<endl;
    display(myList);
}
```

The remove function is in main. It is not removing the correct element. For example, in the list of 1 2 3 4 5, if I try to remove 3 it is removing 2.

Comment: Q&D: `if(nodePtr->getItem()==target)` -> `if(nodePtr->getNext()->getItem()==target)`

Comment: Unrelated: never #include .cpp files. That will lead to slow compile times and duplicate definitions down the line. Figure out how to build C++ projects properly as separate translation units, using a build system like CMake or Make

Comment: @user1810087
Now I am unable to remove the head element. I am unable to find whats the error in that? If I give the input as 1 2 3 4 5, my head is 5 since i am inserting all of my elements in front of linked list. If I try to remove 5, my remove function is not working.